# Gson, JsonElement, String comparison in Java

Tags: java, gson

Ok, I'm wondering this could be quite simple and stupid but after a while fighting with the situation I have no idea what is happening.

I'm using Gson to handle a few JSON elements. Somewhere in my code I get one of the JsonElements of a JsonObject as a String and I compare it against another String. As far as I can see both of them are equals but when comparing I always get false. Here is the snippet.

```
    JsonArray arr;
    JsonObject jsonobj;
    JsonElement model_elem;
    String STUPID_STRING = "bla bla bla";

    // Previously we initializes and fill arr, it doesn't matter how... I hope
    jsonobj = arr.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
    model_elem = jsonobj.get("coolname");
    if (model_elem.toString().equals(STUPID_STRING)) {
        ...
```

It never goes inside the if statement.

arr has element at index 0, jsonobj has a field with name "coolname" and if I println model_elem i get "bla bla bla" (the same as STUPID_STRING). I have tried equals() and also compareTo() == 0.

I cannot figure out what is happening here, does anyone knows? :-s.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe you need to use `getAsString()` with GSON.  `toString()` will add quotes!

Comment: OMG GUYS!! I have discovered the problem!.

Comment: i've been there too.  staring at two equal strings, you don't notice the extra quotes.  :)

Comment: you're totally right, that was the problem... I don't know how to say... that should be documented in JsonElement.toString() and JsonElement.getAsString() xDD

Comment: @orbfish, excuse me, first time I see this