# Invalid new ObjectID(id) but its a valid ID in the DB

Tags: java, json, mongodb, deserialization, objectid

im trying to convert a String id from the page in a new ObjectID, so i can work using it person.getId();

the page send a String id, but to populate, i have to transform it in a ObjectID (or it will print "EXPECTED A OBJECT BUT WAS A STRING)

so i created a deserialize that intercept the jsonElement before it go to the Person object

```
@Override
    public ObjectId deserialize(JsonElement jsElement, Type Type,
            JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        //the id that i receive is this one -> 53c9e605278cd4d23e1152bb

        ObjectId obj = new ObjectId(jsElement.toString());
        return obj;
    }
```

in this way i get this error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid ObjectId ["53c9e605278cd4d23e1152bb"]
```

but if i use in this way:

```
  @Override
        public ObjectId deserialize(JsonElement jsElement, Type Type,
                JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

            //the id that i receive is this one -> 53c9e605278cd4d23e1152bb

            ObjectId obj = new ObjectId("53c9e605278cd4d23e1152bb");
            return obj;
        }
```

it work, why? if it get the id directly from the JsonElement = not working, but if i use ctrl c + ctrl v, it work!!

Answer (score 0):

Accidentaly i found the answer,

.toString() add quotes, i need to use .getAsString

[Gson, JsonElement, String comparison in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585351/gson-jsonelement-string-comparison-in-java)